# How to remove tags from attribute of HTML tag in php?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have a large amount of post generated with old CMS. It is in HTML markup...almost...the worse of I ever seen before. It contains such constructs:

```
....<IMG alt="Хит сезона - <b>Лучшие фразы...</b>" src="http://www.example.com/articles/pic.jpg" align=left>...
```

As you can see strictly it is not a HTML, becouse it contains tegs inside tag attributes.

**I need to remove any tags from HTML attributes.**

I had tried to use parsing through DOMDocument, but it [cannot output cyrilic symbols correctly if headers body and html are not in parsed string](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32547). And even if it does I have to remove them from output.

**The question is how to remove tags from attribute of HTML tag in PHP?**

Is preg_replace is suitable for this?

Comment: what about HTML Tidy: http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/ ?

Comment: Whether regexes are suitable is continent on the scope of replacement. Are all the problems in <IMG> attributes or is this a problem for generic tags? Are tags nested recursively (e.g. <IMG alt="foo <IMG src=...>" ...>)?

Comment: @Zulkhaery: HTML Tidy interesting, but it is a standalone application. This is one of problems I had faced while writing wordpress import plugin. I do not want to bind to external applications.

Comment: @Conrad: no I had not seen such constructions there. only text markup tags such as `<i><b><em><p><br>` and so on. No images inside image description.

Comment: @Yuriy OK, that's promising.  And are they all in <IMG> tags or are there other tags that have been contaminated?

Comment: @Conrad No, actually I faced this problem becouse I had to remove images which are not available... but could not do so because regex `/<img[^>]+src=\"rexexpEscapedImageURL\"[^>]+>/i` could not correctly remove such constructions.

Comment: Tidy is bundled with php so there should be no problem of using it
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
preg_replace('#<([^ ]+)((\s+[\w]+=((["\'])[^\5]+\5|[^ ]+))+)>#e', '"<\\1" . str_replace("\\\'", "\'", strip_tags("\\2")) . ">"', $code);
```

It takes every html opening tag (`<something>`), matches all the attributes `name="value" name='value' name=value` then it tag-strips them. The `str_replace` is necessary because when the `e` modifier is added, PHP use `addslashes` to every match before evaluating it.

I tested it and it seems to work fine. :)